# jQuery adding functionality to dynamic content

Tags: jquery, dynamic, replace, behavior

I'm maintaining a Drupal website in which we've recently installed Google-CSE module - which indexes and provides search results.

Using jQuery, I need to amend the titles of the nodes resulting from searches. That's neccesary because the search results are loaded dynamically into the already loaded search results page.

Using the following code:

```
(function ($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.cse = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {

            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                checkContainer();
            });

            function checkContainer(){
                if( $('div#___gcse_0 div.gsc-resultsbox-visible').is(':visible') ){
                    $('div#___gcse_0 div.gs-title a.gs-title').each(
                        function(){
                            $(this).css('color', 'green');
                            text = $(this).text();
                            $(this).text( text.replace('| MATCHING TEXT TOBE SUBSTITUTED','---***---') );
                        }
                    );
                }else{
                    setTimeout(checkContainer, 50);
                }
            }
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

The code above works on the first page of the search results but fails when subsequent pages are loaded via ajax.

I'll be honest, I don't know how behaviors are correctly implemented. While researching solutions to this problem, I read behaviors can be attached to dynamically created elements. But, I'm not getting the desired result.

Comment: checkContainer is called on document ready only. you have to bind the dynamically added data and call checkContainer again.

Comment: @NidhinChandran: Thanks but I need a bit more help, please. I'm new at this.

Comment: can you share the ajax function. I think you just need to call checkContainer once the ajax call is over. And you can do it inside 'ajax done'

Comment: @NidhinChandran: That's the problem. I have no control nor access to the ajax function code. The ajax function is the Drupal search results pagination functionality i:e the ajax functionality that executes when you click on NEXT to load another 10 results

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:-

Try using `ajaxComplete`. Whenever an ajax request completes `ajaxComplete` will be triggered.

`$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  checkContainer();
});`

OLD:

Assuming that your container id is `#container` where data is loaded via ajax.

`jQuery(document).on('change', '#container', function() {
  checkContainer();
});`

Comment: Change event is detected only on input fields, textareas and select list elements. It can't be used to trigger a response when ajax loads aspects of a page